# Keystore Alias lost Google Developer

Tags: android, alias, keystore, android-keystore

I archived my keystore file and its password and used a software to build my apps (Monaca). Now i programmed them using React and Expo, and i have to indicate may keystore file, its password AND **the same for the Keystore Alias**, but i don't have it.

There's a way of talking with the support of Google Developer by email or phone?
Or anyone knows what can I do?

***...remembering that I have the keystore file, but not the Alias Keystore...***

Answer (score 1):

If you have `password` then you can get alias from `keystore` file:

Goto to bin folder in command prompt `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin>`

Add command `keytool -v -list -keystore keystorePath`

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin>keytool -v -list -keystore keystorePath
```